# Storing all checked responses to get those checked item on app start automatically

Tags: android

I have made Navigation Drawer and used **recyclerView** for **checkBoxes** in drawer item.
Now I wanted all checkbox which was ***checked*** before app is **closed** to **get checked** in **onCreate** of navigation drawer.

Here is my **adapter** class see :

```
class NavigationDrawerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NavigationDrawerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    List<NavDrawerItem> data = Collections.emptyList();
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;
    private int selected_position = -1;
    private static String sel=null;



    NavigationDrawerAdapter(Context context, List<NavDrawerItem> data) {
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void delete(int position) {
        data.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_drawer_row, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {


        final NavDrawerItem current = data.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());



        holder.title.setText(current.getTitle());
        holder.title.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public boolean isChecked(){
                if(holder.title.isChecked()){
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

                if(isChecked()){
                    sel
                }

                if (!current.isShowNotify()){
                    current.setShowNotify(true);
                }else {
                    current.setShowNotify(false);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public void setPref(SharedPreferences pref){

    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return super.getItemId(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public void setHasStableIds(boolean hasStableIds) {
        super.setHasStableIds(hasStableIds);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CheckBox title;

        MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        }
    }
}
```

I guess I have to do something here that's why I posted only this class.
I have ***FragmentDrawer*** class too but I think I need to do something here first , I am not able to use ***sharedpreferences*** Please help

Answer (score 0):

euse the checked data in array save it in some shared prefrence in gragment drawer , you need to check whether that array is available or not, If available populate the responses in checkboxes

```
SharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor=prefs1.edit();
    editor.putString("","");
editor.commit();
// according to your need what you need to store .

    prefs1.getString("","");
// now get the stored content with this when you need to populate the data
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////PUT THIS IN ONCHECKCHANGED //////////////

```
Fragmentdrawer fd=new FragmentDrawer();
fd.somemethod(position,ischecked,context);
```

and made a method in fragment drawer use it to get position in fragment drawer

Comment: I am not able save these data since it days "cannot resolve method getSharedPreferences"

Comment: in oncheckchanged try adding response in in arraylist with respect to its position , then save it to shared prefrence

Comment: position ? yeah thats what I wanted how to get the position of each titile?

Comment: you are using oncheckchange in on bind of recyclerview ADAPTER there is an argument that is position, Use that position

Comment: I know but that I have in Fragment Drawer Class how to get that in Adapter? come to discussion so that I can post all code to review can you open discussion window in comment?

Comment: Have you come with any solution?

Comment: FragmentDrawer fd= new Fragment Drawer();

Comment: Please check the updaTED ANSWER

Comment: If this is your problem then make it static

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130685/discussion-between-sameerkhan1406-and-vikas-rana).